# How do I show the relationship between $I_n:=\int_{0}^{\pi}sin(x)^ndx$ and $I_n:=\frac{n-1}{n}I_{n-2}$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, recurrence-relations

How do I show the relationship between $$I_n:=\int_{0}^{\pi}sin(x)^ndx$$ and   $$I_n:=\frac{n-1}{n}I_{n-2}$$
for when $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n≥2$

Comment: Hint: $\sin(x)^n = \sin(x)^{n-1} \sin(x)$ and integrate by parts.

Comment: twice ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: By the way, this must have been asked before. I only find [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635287/w-n-int-0-pi-2-sinnx-dx-find-a-relation-between-w-n2-and-w-n?rq=1) at the moment, but I guess a better search will make this question into a duplicate.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.vias.org/calculus/07_trigonometric_functions_05_03.html

Comment: this includes a solution (by Norbert) to your question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575737/a-sinn-x-integral

Comment: I found this by using the search option, in particular see http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=int_0%5E%7Bpi%7D+sin%5En+x